# solution of a linear underdetermined system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, computational-mathematics

Is there any **numerical method**  to find vector that satisfies an underdetermined system of linear equations?

**Example**:

- $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$
- Let $A$ be $ n \times m$
- Let $\mathbf{x}$ be $ m \times 1$
- $m>n$

This system has infinitude of solutions, need any one of them

Comment: Check out "minimum norm solution": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_involving_the_Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Minimum-norm_solution_to_a_linear_system

Comment: Do you want a (slightly) Matlab oriented solution ?

Comment: Better not, cause i implementing programm in c++ and solution kinda matlab can be "heavy" for stand alone app. But really appreciate any solution

Comment: You vould use generalised inverses, eg Moore-Penrose or Drazin $\overline {A}$.  A solution then is $\overline{A}b $.

Comment: Are you using a C++ matrix library such as Eigen?

Comment: Don't use any special libs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a splitting of $A=[\ \underbrace{A_1}_{n \times n} \ \ | \  \underbrace{A_2}_{n \times (m-n)}]$ and a vertical splitting for the unknown vector $x=\binom{x_1}{x_2}$, $x_1$ being $n \times 1$ and $x_2$ being  $(m-n) \times 1$.

Thus, initial system $Ax=b$ becomes:

$$A_1x_1+A_2x_2=b \ \ \iff $$

$$\tag{1}A_1x_1=\underbrace{b-A_2x_2}_{b_3}.$$

Giving **any value** to vector $x_2$, the **square** system (1) $A_1x_1=b_3$ has in general, a unique solution.

It remains to "pile up" $x_1$ and $x_2$ to generate a solution $x$.